# Update cell value with GoogleSheets Api

Tags: php, google-sheets

i can update an cell value with Google Api?

already i can read all values from an google sheet, but i cant update any value.

i try this:

```
   $body = new Google_Service_Sheets_ValueRange(array(
          'values' => $locations
        ));
        $params = array(
          'valueInputOption' => $locations
        );

        $result2 = $service->spreadsheets_values->update($spreadsheetId, "A1",  $body, $params);
      print($result2);
```

but i get this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Google_Service_Exception: {
 "error": {
   "code": 400,
   "message": "Invalid value at 'data.values[0]' (type.googleapis.com/google.pr
otobuf.ListValue), \"Stant 1\"\nInvalid value at 'data.values[1]' (type.googleap
is.com/google.protobuf.ListValue), \"Stant 10\"\nInvalid value at 'value_input_o
ption' (TYPE_ENUM), \"\"",
   "errors": [
     {
       "message": "Invalid value at 'data.values[0]' (type.googleapis.com/googl
e.protobuf.ListValue), \"Stant 1\"\nInvalid value at 'data.values[1]' (type.goog
leapis.com/google.protobuf.ListValue), \"Stant 10\"\nInvalid value at 'value_inp
ut_option' (TYPE_ENUM), \"\"",
       "domain": "global",
       "reason": "badRequest"
     }
   ],
   "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
 }
}
```

Comment: can you print `$params` ?

Comment: i find the olution, thankyou, and yes, $options was the problem, should do this :$params = array('valueInputOption' => 'RAW');

Answer (score 3):

ok thankyou, i find the solution ->

```
$options = array('valueInputOption' => 'RAW');
```

http://ajaxray.com/blog/store-data-to-google-sheets-using-php/

```
$options = array('valueInputOption' => 'RAW');
    $values = [
        ["Name", "Roll No.", "Contact"],
        ["Anis", "001", "+88017300112233"],
        ["Ashik", "002", "+88017300445566"]
    ];
    $body   = new Google_Service_Sheets_ValueRange(['values' => $values]);

    $result = $service->spreadsheets_values->update(SHEET_ID, 'A1:C3', $body, $options);
    print($result->updatedRange. PHP_EOL);
```